# Javascript forEach on empty array [].forEach.call

Tags: javascript

Please can someone explain what this command does in javascript or how this language feature is called? Why is there `forEach` on empty array?

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-text-field'), function (el) {
  new MDCTextField(el);
});
```

I am new to frontend technologies.

Comment: Please refer to this reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call - The code you provide is a hack that is unecessary. It passes the first argument to `call()` to the `forEach()` method of the array. The array is empty, but the first argument contains a DOM NodeList that can act like an array. So this basically uses the `forEach()` method to iterate over the DOM elements. It isn't necessary because the DOM NodeList object has a forEach method.

Comment: @RandyCasburn "*It isn't necessary because the DOM NodeList object has a forEach method*"–That code is likely legacy. `NodeList#forEach` is not supported in Internet Explorer and other older browsers.

Comment: Here is the reference to the [DOM NodeList API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) - There you will find it has a `forEach()` method so the hack is not required. All that is needed is this: `document.querySelectorAll(...).forEach(...)`

Comment: Yes, @str is correct - if this is legacy code use for IE, then there is no choice but to use this hack.

Comment: `[].forEach` is a shorthand for `Array.prototype.forEach`